# Have a repeating image extend outside of its containing/parent element?

Tags: html, css

I have a repeating image along the bottom of the page that is contained within the "main" element, and I wish for it to extend along the entire x-axis; right now, "main" has a fixed width, and so the image only repeats up until that point.

How might I get it to extend beyond that? As in, the entire x-axis?

main:

```
.main {
margin:0 auto;
width:960px;
position:relative;
}
```

footer:

```
footer  {
padding:49px 20px 0;
height:98px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-image: url(../images/bg_bottom.png);
}
```

Source implementation:

```
<div class="main">
        <footer>

                [content]

        </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't moving the background-image rule to the footer do it?

Comment: ... Is it not already applied to the footer in the CSS?

Comment: He means of the actual html page set the background image by positioning at the bottom an using repeat-x.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar... isn't it a deprecated method?

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you will have to use positions. In particular, you will need a footer with `position:absolute` and `width:100%` (and inside that, the image with `background-repeat:repeat-x`).

You can find more info searching for footer positions, for example:

[Fixed-position footers](http://mark-allen.net/notes/layout/footer/)

[Fixed Footer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/)

[Putting CSS Footers in Their Place](http://www.kathymarks.com/archives/2005/09/putting_css_footers_in_their_place.html)